# How to hide/disabled the file tab(which also calls backstage view) in word 2010+

Tags: c#, eclipse, com, ms-word, filetable

I'm developing a web-word control which aims to open the word in web page to edit or save...
and I find that there is a tab calls file tab(left/top) in word 2010+, it will open a new window contains many functions, but i don't need it in my control, especially the close button(right/top). so I want to hide/disabled the file tab.
when I search on web, I cant find any solution, just like they say, Microsoft haven't provide interfaces for us to disabled this special tab.
but I think must be some methods to solve it, because the file tab is hidden when I open the word using `eclipse`

Comment: why tagging with eclipse?

Comment: my problem is solved in eclipse, and i want the effect just like the word in eclipse editor, so i hope get some suggestions if someone konw how the eclipse ide to solve. need i del this tag?